# Endless Security Certificate Errors

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

Recently Internet Explorer 8 has started displaying the information bar on almost every web site I visit, with the following message:

> To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors.

So far none of the pages I'm visiting are even using SSL. I've tried the following suggestions from various web sites to no avail:

- check the system date and time - already set correctly
- reinstall latest root certificates update - done
- disable check for certificate revocation - done
- delete expired certificates - could only delete one

This is frustrating to the point where I'm having to use another browser, but I can't accept that it's not fixable. I'm using Microsoft Security Essentials if that matters.

Comment: At home or at work? Do you use a proxy server between IE and the Internet?

Comment: At home. No proxy server, but I was messing around with some a few days ago. I think this may have started after that too. One of them must have done something to my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try resetting Internet Explorer's settings to their default state.

You can do this by going to `Tools` and then opening the `Internet Options` window. Go to the `Advanced` tab and click the `Reset...` button, and then click `Reset` in the window that pops up. Once this is done, close Internet Explorer and reopen it, and see if this fixes your problem.

For more information on which settings are changed, or to see a video walkthrough, check out [Microsoft KB 923737, *How to reset Internet Explorer settings*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737)

Comment: Perfect, everything is back to normal again. Many thanks!