# https sites have stopped working on all browsers

Tags: windows-7, certificate, ssl-certificate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continually getting Certificate Errors on all browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/223024/continually-getting-certificate-errors-on-all-browsers)

I cannot open any https site on my Windows 7 computer without getting security errors (using any browser) My date and time are set correctly. Non-https sites work fine. My computer worked fine for about a year and then suddenly stopped working.

It may be that I installed some certificate and then it stopped working, but I am not sure.

When I try and access https://www.google.com on Chrome I get

```
You attempted to reach www.google.com, but the server presented a certificate 
issued  by an entity that is not trusted by your computer's operating system. 
This may mean that the server has generated its own security credentials, 
which Google Chrome cannot rely on for identity information, or an attacker 
may be trying to intercept your communications. You should not proceed, 
especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.
```

When I try and access https://www.google.com on Firefox I get

```
This Connection is Untrusted
You have asked Firefox to connect securely to www.google.com, but we can't confirm
that your connection is secure.
Normally, when you try to connect securely,
sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are
going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.

What Should I Do?

If you usually connect to 
this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is
trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.
```

When I try and access it on IE I get

```
There is a problem with this website's security certificate.   
The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a 
trusted certificate authority.
Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or 
intercept any data you send to the server.
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: It also appears that the message for Firefox is incorrect because it has the same text as the Chrome message.

Comment: Hi DragonLord.  Thank you. Firstly, I fixed the message for Firefox. Secondly, I did see the similar question you quote before posting, but my laptop has worked fine for a year or so and then suddenly it stopped working, whereas the other question concerned a new laptop.  I updated my question accordingly

Comment: @gordon613: Have you tried downloading the certificates as mentioned in the similar question? Did it help?

Comment: Hi Cerberus. I understood that downloading the certificates is done automatically by Windows Update in Windows 7.  I ran Windows Update and it didn't say anything about certificates.  Also, I did not see a place where I could download the certificates (other than one-by-one)

Comment: I saw this [link](http://dreamlayers.blogspot.com/2009/12/windows-7-cant-always-automatically.html) which seemed to be the same problem as for me. (and as I think @cerberus was suggesting.) However the download was for Windows XP, and didn't work when I ran it. I tried importing the certificates manually from this file anyway, but to no avail