# Your connection is not private in Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer, https, ssl-certificate

There is a problem with my Google Chrome and Internet Explorer when I am visiting **https** sites mostly *google.com* and anything related to Google is not working...

See screenshot of chrome and internet explorer

[image: See screenshot of chrome and internet explorer 9 here]

Sometimes Mozilla also refuses connections but all the way it is working on Mozilla.

I have tried so many tips/tricks found on the internet but nothing works like, **date change, windows update, reinstalling chrome** but either way nothing works for me.

So, I came to Superuser for this solution, and I know I will get the solution. Please help me with this error.

**And yes there is a no option of proceed anyway in advanced on chrome**

**I have gone through an automatic updater of untrusted certificates available for Windows 7 but that doesnt work for me as answer given for [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/223024/continually-getting-https-certificate-errors-on-all-browsers)**

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: You said you have changed date, are you sure time zone is correct as well.

Comment: The problem mentioned in IE points to a problem with root certificates.

Comment: @JuliePelletier By the looks of it, **The Screenshot**. Quite sure it is Windows 7

Comment: @JuliePelletier I am using windows 7 ultimate updated with service pack 1

Comment: Yes @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like , time zone is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continually getting https Certificate Errors on all browsers](http://superuser.com/questions/223024/continually-getting-https-certificate-errors-on-all-browsers)

Comment: @CodeMountain Turn off antivirus if you have any and see if it helps. Also try trye `BADIDEA` in Chrome when you have that error, it should let you move on

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I dont have any antivirus software installed on my PC

Comment: Most likely a problem with root certificates. Firefox has it's own separate certificate store. IE & Chrome use the store that comes with Windows.

Comment: @DavidDai I have updated root certificates provided by a Microsoft, automatic updater tool, still no luck

Comment: How are you connecting to internet ? Is there any proxy ? Or try **Ultrasurf** just for fun